# Angular - How to change Style on a dynamically created input in a FormBuilder depending on each value?

Tags: angular, input, styles, formbuilder

I'm trying to make red the text inserted in a dynaymically created input (as many as the button is pressed) but I cannot get it right. I don't know how to access the value of the input in this case. 
I want to change the text depending on the condition that if the inserted number is bigger than other input in the form, its color becomes red.

This is the html

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
  <label>
    Capacidad
    <input type="text" formControlName="capacidad" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Max. Casas
    <input type="text" formControlName="maxcasas" />
  </label>
  <div formArrayName="pesos">
    <button (click)="addPeso()">Añadir peso</button>
    <button (click)="deleteAllPesos()">Resetear</button>
    <div *ngFor="let peso of pesos.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>
        Peso:
        <input [style.color]="<<<<value bigger than formulario.capacidad ? "red" ; "black">>>>> type="number"  formControlName="peso" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Nombre:
        <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" type="text" />
      </label>
      <button (click)="deletePeso(i)">Borrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the relevant part of the ts

```
 public formulario = this.fb.group({
    capacidad: ["5"],
    maxcasas: ["3"],
    pesos: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        peso: this.fb.control(""),
        nombre: this.fb.control("")
      })
    ])
  });
  get pesos() {
    return this.formulario.get("pesos") as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: I think my answer should work but if not put an stackblitz and I can checkout it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarily to other answer, check the value of the specific form control in the loop, you can do it by the following:

```html
[style.color]="pesos.at(i).get('peso').value > formulario.get('capacidad').value ? 'red' : 'black'"
```

**[STACKBLITZ](http://%3Chello%20name=%22%7B%7B%20name%20%7D%7D%22%3E%3C/hello%3E)**

EDIT: But you can also do `pesos.controls[i].controls.peso.value`, but I like to use `at` and `get`.

Comment: Edit: Worked. I don't quite understand why use at(x) instead of [x], same with "get". But thanks for your help.

Comment: `get` is just a (cleaner) shortcut, instead of using `controls` to traverse. `at` we use, since it's an formarray. Also we could traverse trough the array using `.controls`, but again, this is cleaner, at least in my opinion :) But I understand the confusion you are talking about - formarray vs "normal" array.

Comment: so you can also do `pesos.controls[i].controls.peso.value` but I think using `at` and `get` is cleaner. But your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are accesing programatically
this. formulario.get("capacidad") // FormControl

````
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
  <label>
    Capacidad
    <input type="text" formControlName="capacidad" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Max. Casas
    <input type="text" formControlName="maxcasas" />
  </label>
  <div formArrayName="pesos">
    <button (click)="addPeso()">Añadir peso</button>
    <button (click)="deleteAllPesos()">Resetear</button>
    <div *ngFor="let peso of pesos.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>
        Peso:
        <input [style.color]="formulario.get('pesos').get(i).get('peso').value > formulario.get("capacidad").value ? "red" ; "black" type="number"  formControlName="peso" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Nombre:
        <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" type="text" />
      </label>
      <button (click)="deletePeso(i)">Borrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```
````